# Is there a way to find file type?

Tags: delphi

I would like to get the type of a file without using the extension, is there a way to use the metadata of a file to distinguish if it is a video file or if it isnt?

I have tried using extensions but I find searching each file extension and comparing it with a list of extensions is quite time consuming.

Comment: Not necessarily. Some file types will have some unique signature, while others won't.

Comment: Linux has the `file` command which uses various methods to get or guess the file type by the contents.

Comment: Well, it depends. Some types can be distinguished by a signature, some can't. However, it is way faster to compare extension than to read the file. Whatever makes you think that is time consuming, is quite wrong.

Comment: FWIW, as David mentions, opening and reading the first few bytes of any file is way more time consuming than just using the file extension. I think your real problem is behind whatever code you have which doesn't perform to your requirements. Perhaps post a new question asking about that, with enough detail that we can identify your bottleneck(s) and help you fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to determine file type without using the file extension. You can do this by reading the file header also sometimes referred as file signature which occupies first few bytes of the file.

How many bytes do file header/signature occupy? This depends from file type to file type. So you should check the internet for more detailed information about the file header/signature for specific file type you want to identify.

You can find list of some more popular signatures [List of file signatures - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

PS: Most program stopped relying only on file signatures for determining file way back when first Windows came out. The main reason for this was the fact that since in the beginning file extensions were limited to three character length (limit of the old file systems like old FAT8 or FAT16) world quickly ran out of possible file extensions so multiple programs began to use same file extensions but used completely different file types. So by storing file header/signature at the beginning of the file you would no longer be limited by this file system limitation.

Comment: That should be "possible to determine **some** file types", imo.

Comment: "Most program stopped relying only on file signatures for determining file way back when first Windows came out." This isn't true at all. What happens when you double click a file in Windows?

Comment: @David AFAIK, when you double-click a file in Windows, it uses the file extension to identify which program it should open with. Which I believe was the point here. Can you share an instance you know of where double-clicking a file reads the first few bytes of the file to determine what program to open it with?

Comment: @SilverWarior Perhaps modify "only on file signatures" to "only on reading the first few bytes" and it would be more fitting.

Comment: @Jerry It was a rhetorical question. The shell uses the extension to identify the file type.

Comment: @Indeed it was, but you said "This isn't true at all". What's not true about it?

Comment: @Jerry - I think what is not true is the correct wording/meaning. That sentence would probably read *"most programs stopped relying only on file extensions"* for the paragraph to make some sense.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes Windows explorer is still relying on file extension association in order to quickly determine which program to use in order to try to open specific file. But after that program is launched and the filename passed as first parameter the program itself no longer relies only on file extension but rather reads file header in order to determine if the file is indeed of a specific type. if the file doesn't have specific header the program returns an error message saying that the file you are trying to open doesn't have a proper file type ...

Comment: ... But if you go and rename such file so that you change its extension to something completely different and still try to open it using the previously mention program it is quite likely that the mentioned program will open that file just fine even thou the file extension is wrong.